# Incremental auto online update with Install4J

Tags: installation, install4j

I need some help regarding Install4J and the auto online update function.
We have a JRE bundled Install4J installer which works fine. We use the auto online update functionality which works fine, too. All this functionality in integrated to a continuous integration process in TeamCity.

Unfortunately the update installation setup file has a size of around 100MB which is inconvenient to download if we only want to apply a patch or a minor update.

As far as I have understood from other similar questions and the Install4J documentation the right way to deal with that is using a second project file with another application ID and setting up an Add-On-Installer which only contains relevant files and points to the full installer application ID.
To enable the auto online update functionality I have to upload the update.xml file from the Add-On installer, am I right?

By the way, does the Add-on online auto update procedure automatically detect the locally installed version correctly?

But in that case we have to adapt the add-on installer each and every time we are deploying a new patch or minor feature which is difficult to implement in the CI process.

Is there a way to configure an Install4J installer so that it automatically gets the information online which elements have to be updated so that the download size is as small as possible and we could just use one default add-on installer which contains all sources beside the JRE bundle?
Something like an online incremental update procedure which is managed internally by Install4J?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use the add-on installer for updating, because it cannot change the version number.

In order to get smaller update installers, you create a second project where the distribution tree only contains the changed files - or at least does not contain some large files that did not change. To do that, you simply copy the original installer and delete the files in the distribution tree that you do not need to update.

Then you build two sets of installers, those for a new installation and those for the update.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I tried what you have mentioned. Unfortunately it did not work the way I have expected. Most probably I am still having some misconfiguration.

Comment: Most probably I am still having some misconfiguration. Filtering all not needed files within the application folders results in uninstalling all the other files during update procedure which should just remain in the application folder. I removed the uninstaller from the copied installer configuration but in that case no file is updated. Do you have any idea what I am missing to solve this? I am sure its some trivial thing but I am just not getting where I want to ... thx

Comment: Probably you have an "Uninstall previous installation" action attached to the "Installation" screen.

Comment: Sure! Works like a charm now. Thanks again for the helpful and fast reply.

Comment: If it is always the same files that change (e.g. application jar, certain data files), could this also be done by utilising downloadable installation components, and programmatically toggling the big "core" package on `context.isUpgradeInstallation`?